# using A4J, how do I rerender a javascript function, and call it after rerendering?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

for example, I've tried

```
<a4j:region id="scriptSuggested" >
<f:verbatim>
<script>
  reallyUpdateIt = function () {
       // javascript code that changes after aj4 ajax call is triggered
      }
    </script>
   </f:verbatim>
    <a4j:jsFunction reRender="scriptSuggested" ignoreDupResponses="true" ajaxSingle="true" name="updateSuggestionValues" action="#{bean.action}" oncomplete="reallyUpdateIt();">
        <a4j:actionparam name="userInput" assignTo="#{bean.input}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</a4j:region>
```

I would expect that calling the javascript function

```
updateSuggestionValues('val');
```

is going to do the action

```
#{bean.action}
```

and after that it would rerender the region `scriptSuggested` and finally would call `reallyUpdateIt()` ,

all works except the part of updating the code  of `reallyUpdateIt()`, I checked the ajax response using firebug, and it comes with the expected new javascript code, but when I call `reallyUpdateIt()` , the old code is triggered.

I am using JSF 1.2, richfaces 3.3.3,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out using `<a4j:region id="scriptSuggested" >` doesn't generate an html section that A4J can rerender, I had to use  `<a4j:outputPanel>` , so now it updates the function, my code now looks like :

```
<a4j:region >
<a4j:outputPanel id="scriptSuggested">  
<f:verbatim>
<script>
  reallyUpdateIt = function () {
       // javascript code that changes after aj4 ajax call is triggered
      }
    </script>
   </f:verbatim>
    <a4j:jsFunction reRender="scriptSuggested" ignoreDupResponses="true" ajaxSingle="true" name="updateSuggestionValues" action="#{bean.action}" oncomplete="reallyUpdateIt();">
        <a4j:actionparam name="userInput" assignTo="#{bean.input}" />
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</a4j:region>
```