# retrieving value from backing bean and displaying on form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a a4j:commandbutton on my jsf page. Following is the code extract-

```
<a4j:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="#{msgsMass.MM_04_02_BTN_CONTINUE}"
    reRender="addNewCardForm,saveAddNewCardForm" immediate="true"
    action="#{bBean.retrieveOrderId}" oncomplete="addNewCreditCard()" >
```

addNewCardForm, saveAddNewCardForm are html forms on the page which are displayed and submitted in the javascript call of addNewCreditCard().

In these forms I have an input field which will display the value from bBean.retrieveOrderId. However this bean method is called only after the forms are loaded with blank values for orderId.

Please let me know how I can get the orderId value on the form fields when the form is displayed to the user.

Comment: Save orderId in form bean during retrieveOrderId action

Comment: I am. The problem is orderId is always blank when I login- first time when the page loads

Comment: It is not related to `a4j:commandButton` (see your code) and form submit (see question title). You need setup bean data (for example orderId) before redirect to page (where it is displayed).

Comment: okay, let me clarify. I have a payment page in my application.The commandButton is called when the user wants to proceed with the payment. On this button click, I am displaying a 3rd party form in an iframe. In this form I need to fetch and display a unique orderId. So this orderId is being generated in bBean.retrieveOrderId. once retrieved I am storing it in the bBean property orderId which has the corresponding getters and setters.

Comment: Now when I call the third part form and pass-in the orderId field in the input value it gets its from the bean getter method. The form itself if called on the oncomplete javascript funcion "addNewCreditCard". Since in the commandButton the action is called first then the oncomplete, I was expecting the orderId getter to have values when it is loaded. But somehow the form is getting loaded before the action is called

Comment: It's not a problem that form is loaded before the action. But this form should be **re-rendered** after action. And you already have code for that. It should work (if not try with <a4j:region>).

Comment: The target for the form is an iframe. I tried re-rendering the form, iframe and the also the inputfied for orderId itself. Nothing seems to work.Which component should be re-rendered exactly ? I have never used a4j:region ..will try

Comment: it is an html form submit used to submit to third party site -- not a jsf form. I am not sure if I can use a4j:region here

Comment: The orderId is generated on successive page loads but the first time when the user logsin it is blank

Comment: One more thing, the form is not on the page until the onComplete is executed. May be I am not doing the right way, please suggest if there are any other alternatives

Comment: thank you for the suggestion to use a4j:region. I followed this link and it resolved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858942/using-a4j-how-do-i-rerender-a-javascript-function-and-call-it-after-rerenderin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments were transformed into answer:

`orderId` will be displayed on form after proper re-rendering. You can do it wrap your form in  `<a4j:region>`.